# Dúvida sobre NS_ENUM

Tags: objective-c

Tenho a seguinte dúvida sobre o NS_ENUM
Estou criando um com três opções:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, VersionStatus) {

   OPTION1,

   OPTION2,

   OPTION3

};
```

Como faço para utilizar else dentro de um switch?

Sendo que o parâmetro de comparação virá de um Serviço?
eles seguem a ordem de criação?

Sendo

```
OPTION1 = 1 (ou zero) , OPTION2 = 2,  OPTION3
```

Answer (score 1):

`enum` (ou enumerated value — “valor enumerado” em português) é uma forma, herdada do C, de declarar valores constantes.

Sua sintaxe base é:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ASRestaurantStatus) {
    ASRestaurantStatusOpen,
    ASRestaurantStatusClosed,
    ASRestaurantStatusRenovating
};
```

O primeiro elemento, sem definição de valor, é sempre zero e os próximos seguem a sequência.

Para usar dentro de um switch, nada muda em relação a um inteiro comum, como por exemplo:

```
switch (currentStatus) {
    case ASRestaurantStatusRenovating: {
    } break;

    case ASRestaurantStatusClosed: {
    } break;

    case ASRestaurantStatusOpen: {
    } break;
}
```

Eles podem ser vistos, em sua essência, como apenas uma definição “segura” de algo.